# MEF: Import doesn't work if place compose code to constructor, but works if place it to a function before return

Tags: dependency-injection, mef

I have the service below.

```
[Export(typeof(IPluginsLoaderService))]
internal class PluginsLoaderService : IPluginsLoaderService
{
    public PluginsLoaderService()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Shapes"));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Behaviours"));
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    [ImportMany(typeof (IBehaviorPlugin))] 
    public IEnumerable<IBehaviorPlugin> BehaviorPlugins { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IGeometryPlugin))]
    public IEnumerable<IGeometryPlugin> ShapePlugins { get; private set; }
}
```

In other class, I import it to a property like this:

```
    [Import]
    public IPluginsLoaderService PluginsLoaderService { get; set; }
```

PluginsLoaderService is not null, but BehaviorPlugins and ShapePlugins properties contains 0 elements.

If place compose parts code to the function like below, the plugins are loaded.

```
[Export(typeof(IPluginsLoaderService))]
internal class PluginsLoaderService : IPluginsLoaderService
{
    [ImportMany(typeof (IBehaviorPlugin))] 
    public IEnumerable<IBehaviorPlugin> BehaviorPlugins { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IGeometryPlugin))]
    public IEnumerable<IGeometryPlugin> ShapePlugins { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<IBehaviorPlugin> GetBehaviorPlugins()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Shapes"));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Behaviours"));
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        return BehaviorPlugins;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IGeometryPlugin> GetShapePlugins()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Shapes"));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Behaviours"));
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        return ShapePlugins;
    }
}
```

Why it happens? How to organize it in better way? Is it possible to do inside MefBootstrapper? Here is my bootstrapper code.

```
    public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window) this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }


    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();


        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(GetType().Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Shapes"));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"..\..\Plugins\Behaviours"));            
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ToolbarModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ToolboxModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(CanvasModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(StatusBarModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IPluginsLoaderService).Assembly));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the composition in a class that is a `MEF` part? Better practice would be to compose all parts once, at application start-up and place the logic for composing in a bootstrapper class that is not a `MEF` composeable part.

Comment: It doesn't work somehow when I try to configure it thru bootstrapper. I'll add a code of my bootstrapper. Could you please look and say what is missing there?